# Pycord Slash command Respond with Embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, embedding, pycord

I have the following Pycord slash command

```
@commands.slash_command(name="testcmd")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def SampleSlashComand(self, ctx: commands.Context,
                       title: Option(str, "title", required=True),
                       description: Option(str, "description", required=True),
                       ):
    await ctx.defer()

    if title == "test":
        return await ctx.respond("hi")

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"{title}",
        description=f"{description}",
        timestamp=datetime.now()
    )
    return await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

When running the slash command with 'title' set to "test", I see the respone "hi" from the bot. However when I use another title, which causes an embedding to be posted, the bot responds with the error "Invalid interaction application command"

Is it possible to have a slash command be responded with a embedding?

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure if this is the answer or not but it appears the issue was that I actually had 2 bots running with the same "token" and slash command. This seems to have messed something up since when I realized and shutdown the duplicate bot everything worked as expected.

Maybe this is the one downside to slash commands, only one bot running can really handle it